# Cannot print document after mail merging is applied

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, office-interop

I try to print the document after I applied mail merging to it but I get the following error:

> **cannot implicitly convert type 'microsoft.interop.word.document' to 'system.drawing.printing.printdocument'**

Here is the code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Open the database connection.
    string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\_Employees\Employee_Database\Database From Excel.accdb";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        // Get data from a database.
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM EmpInfo", conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
        da.Fill(data);

        // Open the template document.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document(@"c:\_Employees\Template\MergeDoc.docx");
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument docToPrint = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

        // Loop though all records in the data source.
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            // Execute mail merge.
            doc.MailMerge.Execute(row);

            docToPrint = (PrintDocument)doc;

            DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();

            // If the result is OK then print the document.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                docToPrint.Print();

            }                    
        }
```

After some changes, theres no error but the page doesn't print.
What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using the "Word interop" you have to print through the Word Application interface. Only Word really knows how to interpret Word content (Zip package of XML and other files) for printing. The .NET Framework's System.Drawing.Printing cannot work with a Word document.

So, as the error message is telling you, you can't cast a Word.Document object to a System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.

You can use the Word object model's Document.Print command, with its parameters if you need to set the number of copies, etc.. Using your code as basis: `doc.Print();`

I don't know what your PrintDialog is for, so can't make a remark as to how to connect that with printing a Word document...